# Unable to use Angular Masonry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-masonry

I've tried using Angular Masonry with their custom directive but have not been successful. I'm getting errors in the console such as :

> TypeError: b.masonry is not a function

I have the Angular script files loaded in my  along with Angular Masonry, Images Loaded.

**My html:**

```
<div masonry column-width = "200">
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in bricks">
        <img ng-src="{{ brick }}" alt="A masonry brick">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','wu.masonry']);

myApp.controller('mainController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.bricks = ['Images/Christina_Ysaguirre_Photography_Copyright_2015_(2).jpg',
                     'Images/Christina Ysaguirre Photography Copyright 2015  (3).jpg',
                     'Images/Christina Ysaguirre Photography Copyright 2015  (4).jpg',
                     'Images/Christina Ysaguirre Photography Copyright 2015  (5).jpg'
                    ];

}]);
```

The Images are loading in the html but Masonry isn't doing anything with them. What can I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

angular-masonry depends on a lot of other node modules. If you installed the package using npm/bower, then the dependencies would already have been downloaded. You still have include them in your index.html or browserify them all into your bundle js file.

**1. The inclusion in index.html approach**
You can add the following lines with paths changed appropriately.

```
    <script src="/static/node_modules/angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/fizzy-ui-utils/node_modules/desandro-matches-selector/matches-selector.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/node_modules/angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/fizzy-ui-utils/node_modules/doc-ready/doc-ready.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/node_modules/angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/fizzy-ui-utils/utils.js"></script>

    <script src="/static/node_modules/angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/get-size/node_modules/desandro-get-style-property/get-style-property.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/node_modules/angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/get-size/get-size.js"></script>

    <script src="/static/node_modules/angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/outlayer/item.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/node_modules/angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/outlayer/outlayer.js"></script>

<script src="/static/node_modules/angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

**2. Browserify dependencies**
This is the preferred approach but requires you the setup appropriate build tools. You could use something like below in your main.js and combined all the dependencies into a single bundle.

```
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/imagesloaded/node_modules/eventie');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/imagesloaded/node_modules/wolfy87-eventemitter');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/imagesloaded');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/jquery-bridget');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/fizzy-ui-utils/node_modules/desandro-matches-selector');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/fizzy-ui-utils/node_modules/doc-ready');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/fizzy-ui-utils');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/get-size/node_modules/desandro-get-style-property');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/get-size');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout/node_modules/outlayer');
require('angular-masonry/node_modules/masonry-layout');
require('angular-masonry');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry/issues/135#issuecomment-192242230 comment made me realized I needed jquery-bridget to be added first on my scripts order..

That solved that error